# Unexpected behaviour with `npm install` of a local project

Tags: npm, npm-link

### Scenario

- I am using `npm 5.8.0`
- I am having a `ProjectA` and a `ProjectB`
- `ProjectB` is a dependency of `ProjectA`
- Both project are being bundled and run via Webpack (I can provide my configuration if necessary).

For development purposes I am referencing `ProjectB` in `ProjectA`'s package.json via `"projectB": "file:../projectB"`. Basically the only files I need there are in the `lib` folder which is Webpack's output.

### Problem

If I install this dependecy with the configuration above, npm will install the entire `ProjectB`-folder into node_modules. It will contain everything `projectB`'s node_modules, configuration files, the src-folder etc.

Apart from the fact that this can't be the expected behaviour, this leads to errors. For example some of the installed @types will throw an error because they are considered duplicates. @types and other packages from `ProjectA` and `ProjectB` seem to "collide". Those packages are referenced as `"dependencies"` in both `ProjectA` and `ProjectB` mostly.

### What I tried

#### npm link

If I use npm link the same (see above) behaviour appears. The entire folder will be installed into `ProjectA`'s node_modules.

#### npm pack

It might be **important** that I actually do have a `.npmignore`-file in `ProjectB`. So when I use `npm pack` a `projectB.tgz` file is generated. If I then install `ProjectB` via `"projectB": "file:../projectB.tgz"` everything works fine. I assume that `npm pack` does take the `.npmignore`-file into account.

My problem with this solution is that I not only would have to build `ProjectB` every time a change is applied to it but also `npm pack` it.

#### Delete `ProjectB`'s node_modules

I guess this is the silliest workaround. If I reference `ProjectB` via `"projectB": "file:../projectB"` again but delete its node_modules after building it, they do not appear after installation. Thus I do not get any more exceptions.

I guess this is not a valid solution either as still the entire `ProjectB`-folder is being installed.

### Question

What is the best practice here? What is a reasonable constallation for `ProjectA` and `ProjectB` in order to install `ProjectB` from a local source?

Answer (score 2):

If `projectA` requires files from `projectB/lib`, you could configure webpack's [resolver](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/) as follows (assuming webpack 4):

```
resolve {
  alias: "projectB": "projectB/lib"
}
```

If `projectB` is a module, it's `package.json` should include the corresponding entrypoint (see [this page](https://shuheikagawa.com/blog/2017/01/05/main-jsnext-main-and-module/)).

I would also suggest you try [yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/en/) instead of npm for package management. Yarn's [workspaces](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/workspaces/) feature is designed for working with multiple interdependent packages.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try putting the following code into the package.json file of projectB?

```
"files": [
    "lib/*"
]
```

This should tell any npm install to only use the files specified in the Array. You can obviously expand these with more entries. See the [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#files) for more details

Answer (score 0):

You could alias `projectB/lib` in the webpack configuration for projectA.  That will tell webpack to look in projectB's `lib` folder when resolving projectB modules.

Example webpack.config:

```
{
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            "projectB": path.resolve(__dirname, '../projectB/lib')
        }
    }
}
```

Also, if projectA is utility library that will be installed in another project, make projectB just a peerDependency of projectA.  That way when projectA is installed, the user will get a warning if projectB is not installed or if an incorrect version is installed.

Example package.json:

```
{
    "peerDependencies": {
        "projectB": "1.0.0"
    }
}
```